# Change the background color of a button in a Recycler view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to change the background color of a specific button in my recycler view when certain conditions are met. How do I get to that specific button?

This is my adapter class :-

> public class mixandmatchadapter extends
> RecyclerView.Adapter<mixandmatchadapter.ViewHolder>{
> private static final String TAG = "RecyclerAdapter";
> List datalist;
> Context context;
> int index;
> String text;
>
> ```
> public mixandmatchadapter(int index, String text) {
>     this.index = index;
>     this.text = text;
> }
> public mixandmatchadapter(List<Mixmatchclass> datalist, Context context) {
>     this.datalist = datalist;
>     this.context = context;
> }
> @NonNull
> @Override
> public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
>     LayoutInflater layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
>     View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_itemmixandmatch,parent,false);
>     ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
>     return viewHolder;
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
>    holder.mainbutton.setText(datalist.get(position).getStatement());
>    //String.valueOf(position))
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getItemCount() {
>     return datalist.size();
> }
>
> class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
>
>     Button mainbutton;
>     public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
>         super(itemView);
>         mainbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainbutton);
>
>     }
> } }
> ```

For example:- If I have ten buttons in my recycler view and I want to change the color of a button at position 5 how would I access it?

This is my main fragment :-

> ```
> public class Mixandmatch extends Fragment {
>     RecyclerView recyclerView; 
>     mixandmatchadapter mixandmatchadapter;
>
>     public  static List<Mixmatchclass> datalist;
>     private static int slideCounter=2;
>     @Override
>     public void onStart() {
>         super.onStart();
>     }
>     public Mixandmatch() {
>         
>     }
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mixandmatch, container,false);
>
>
>         recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rightlyt);
>
>         datalist=new ArrayList<>();
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 2",0));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 4",1));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 1",2));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 5",3));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 3",4));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 7",5));
>         datalist.add(new Mixmatchclass("Statement 6",6));
>
>         recyclerView.setAdapter(new mixandmatchadapter(datalist,getActivity()));
>         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
>
>         ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
>         itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
>
>         return view;
>     }
>     ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new 
>     ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP
>             | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END , 0) {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull 
>         RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
>
>             int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
>             int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
>
>             Collections.swap(datalist,fromPosition,toPosition);
>
>             recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(fromPosition,toPosition);
>             recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
>             return false;
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
>
>         }
>     };
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: onBindViewHolder gets called once for every position, so you could check in onBindviewHolder if(position==5) holder.mainButton.backgroundColor ...

Comment: I also want to add on click listener to a different button,  after clicking that I want to put condition.
It is working fine without setting on click listener but after putting onclicklistener nothing happens.

Comment: sorry you will have to be more specific and ask this in a new seperate question, including your code

Comment: Always make sure to override `getItemId` and `getItemType`